# After verb DO(auxillary verb) main verb should be in base form or V1

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

when we are using DO as auxillary verb the main verb used should be in which form, base form or V1?
Example :I do **understand**. Here 'Understand' is in Base form or V1?

Comment: Base form is the simple answer. V1 is the simple present tense where, as it happens, almost all verbs have an identical base and plain form: "I do **understand**" ~ "I/you/we/you/they **understand**. Hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

After any part of *do* (*do*, *does*, *did*, *done*, *don't*, *doesn't*, *didn't*) the verb  it governs is always in the base form.

**Edit**: I recognise "V1" from questions here as terminology which is used in TESOL, but it is unknown to most English speakers who are not TESOL teachers, and I didn't know what it meant without looking it up: it appears to mean the base form, so I don't understand (!) your question.

Comment: My question is that pure base from of verb which is different from V1( present plural form) is used after Do(does/do/did) or V1( present plural form)? My doubt is that in the example " I do understand". Understand is pure base form or V1( plural form).

Comment: Right. If V1 means "plural form" (different from the base from for precisely one verb in the language: _are_ vs _be_) then the answer is "base form". But [this site](https://englishstudyhere.com/tenses/v1-v2-v3-list/) uses "V1" and "base form" interchangeably.